# Apple Developer Account Link

Tags: ios-appstore, developer-program

Recently I enrolled in Apple developer program. I'm looking for a link through which i can get all my apps that I developed/published.

How i get all apks under one link in app store ?

I've found one developer link in this format:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/<country>/developer/<developer–name>/id<developer-ID>?mt=8
```

From where i get developer-ID for my app store ?

I've app-ID of all my app, through which I can go to single app not my all apps.

Comment: Are you referring to where the apps are in iTunes Connect?

Comment: yes, from where i can get link of all my apps in iTunes connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18727947/3487310):

To find your developer/team ID if you already have an Apple Developer account, you can go to https://developer.apple.com/account/#/membership.

Scroll down to **Team ID** and that's it.

If you don't have a paid developer account you will not have a developer ID.

**Update based on comments**:
[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1633/_index.html).

To find the link for all your apps:

> There are three types of App Store Short Links, in two forms, one for
>   iOS apps, another for Mac Apps:
>
> **Company Name**
>   **iOS**: http://appstore.com/ for example, http://appstore.com/apple
>   **Mac**: http://appstore.com/mac/
>   for example, http://appstore.com/mac/apple
>
> **App Name**
>   **iOS**: http://appstore.com/ for example,
>   http://appstore.com/keynote
>   **Mac**: http://appstore.com/mac/ for
>   example, http://appstore.com/mac/keynote
>
> **App by Company**
>   **iOS**: http://appstore.com// for example, http://appstore.com/apple/keynote
>   **Mac**:
>   http://appstore.com/mac// for example, http://appstore.com/mac/apple/keynote
>
> Most companies and apps have a canonical App Store Short Link. This canonical URL is created by changing or removing certain characters (many of which are illegal or have special meaning in a URL (for example, "&")).
>
> **To create an App Store Short Link, apply the following rules to your
>   company or app name:**
>
> 1. Remove all whitespace Convert all characters to lower-case
> 2. Remove all copyright (©), trademark (™) and registered mark (®) symbols
> 3. Replace ampersands ("&") with "and" Remove most punctuation (See Listing 2 for the set) Replace accented and other "decorated" characters (ü, å,
>      etc.) with their elemental character (u, a, etc.)
> 4. Leave all other characters as-is.

Comment: I know my Team ID but how i get all apps link using that Team ID ? what do you mean by **paid developer account** ?

Comment: Your question asked "From where i get developer-ID for my app store?" so that's what I answered.  I'll update my answer to include the link for all your apps.

Comment: According to my RND _developer-ID_ required to create a link by which i can get all my apps but somehow i'm not able to find that ID. By the way I've mention Apple Developer Account Link in my question title.

Comment: Titles can be misleading and/or completely incorrect which is why I always go by the text of the actual question.

Comment: clicked on above given link on Mac, -> failed to open page ??

Comment: @Aryan Which link?  I clicked on the Membership link in my answer and it worked fine.

Comment: link with Company, App name. and there example too not working

Comment: Also tested in my iOS app. Link  _http://appstore.com/<myname>_  redirect to a blank page that containing text **Cannot connect to App Store.**

Comment: I don't know what's going on with your connection but it works on my Windows machine.  If you have iTunes installed it opened all my apps in iTunes.  If you want to give your company name here, I can try it, too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75321/discussion-between-aryan-and-fsb).

Comment: Its is not working now

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this article from Apple Developer Document:

- [Creating easy-to-read short links to the App Store for your apps and company](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1633/_index.html).